# Clean imports from packages in Python

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.x, package

I have a following project structure:

```
project
|----app.py
|----package
     |---__init__.py
     |---module.py
     |---module2.py
     |---module3.py
     |---....
```

My `__init__.py` file currently is empty. In module.py I have a definition of a class:

```
class UsefulClass:
    ...
```

And in other modules similar definitions as well. My app.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from package.module import UsefulClass
from package.module2 import UsefulClass2
...

usefulclass = UsefulClass()
usefulclass2 = UsefulClass2()
....
```

My question is: how can I replace this `from package.module... import UsefulClass` statements? Even now, I have only 4 modules defined and this imports starting to look ugly. Can I import them in `__init__.py` file and then just use `import package` in `app.py`? I have tried that and it gives me an error.

I am looking for a clean and elegant solution.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, please tell us exactly what you tried, and what error you got (with traceback).

Comment: In `project.package.__init__.py`: import the subpackages and use `__all__ = [...]` http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: I am using Python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3:

`package/__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import bar
```

`package/foo.py`:

```
bar=0
```

`app1.py`:

```
import package
print(package.bar)
```

app2.py:

```
from package import bar
print(bar)
```

Either way, this prints `0`, just as you want.

In Python 2, just change `from .foo import bar` to `from foo import bar`.

(In fact, the 2.x code often works in Python 3, but it's not correct, and in some edge cases it will fail. For example, if you have a `bar.py` at the same level as the app, you'll end up with `bar` being that module, instead of `0`.)

In real life, you probably want to specify a `__all__` from each package and module that you might ever `from foo import …` (if for no other reason than to allow to test things at the interactive interpreter with `from foo import *`).

It sounds like you're saying you already tried this, and got an error. Without knowing *exactly* what you tried, and what the error was, and which Python version you're using, I have no idea what in particular you might have gotten wrong, but presumably you got *something* wrong.

---

The `.foo` specifies a package-relative import. Saying `from .foo import bar` means "from the `foo` module in the same package as me, import `bar`". If you leave off the dot, you're saying "from the `foo` module in the standard module path, import `bar`".

The tutorial section on [Intra-package References](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) (and surrounding sections) gives a very brief explanation. The reference docs for [`import`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) and [the import system in general](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) give most of the details, but the original proposal in [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) explains the details, and the rationale behind the design, a lot more simply.

The reason you need to leave off the dot in 2.x is that 2.x didn't have any way to distinguish relative and absolute imports. There's only `from foo import bar`, which means "from the `foo` module of the same package as me, or, if there is no such module, the one in the standard module path, import `bar`".

Comment: Yeah, I am using Python 3.3 and have tried `from foo import bar` in `__init__.py`, but that does not work. What this `dot` in front of module name means? I checked and your answer works. Thank you